# Unable to access Jenkins UI from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I installed **Jenkins** on **AWS** server and it was working on the browser properly then suddenly **Jenkins** UI does not work on the browser and shows:

> This site can’t be reached

but Jenkins is fully up and running on the server. anyone has idea what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This isn't a programming question.  Perhaps ask in ServerFault.   that said,  it could be a whole slew of items, not limited to 1) Firewall preventing connect,  2) You're not pointing to the right port. 3) Jenkins is set up to listening to localhost only..  There's no details in how you set it up..  Very difficult to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am sure of the points you referred to, it was working fine that is why idk how it stopped.